# Embed Chatango in HTML

Tags: html

How do you add Chatango to your website? I inserted the code for it into my HTML editor and it's not showing up. Here is my script:

```
<script id="cid0020000090122848013" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 589px;height: 583px;">{"handle":"sputnickchat","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"009900","b":100,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","k":"009900","l":"009900","m":"009900","n":"FFFFFF","p":"10","q":"009900","r":100,"cnrs":"0.35","fwtickm":1}}</script>
```

When I insert it inside Dreamweaver it says "syntax error" and doesn't show up on the page.

Here is the link to the website that generates the script
http://chatango.com/

Comment: Works just fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pwy1sra/).  Can you include the HTML container you're using in a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Perhaps the full HTML file you've inserted the script into?

Comment: I tried inserting it in a blank HTML file and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you running it from an `http://` URL?

Comment: No I'm running it from my local files. I just used a blank HTML page and inserted it in the body element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `async src` is missing the protocol:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <script id="cid0020000090122848013" data-cfasync="false" async src="http://st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 589px;height: 583px;">{"handle":"sputnickchat","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"009900","b":100,"c":"FFFFFF","d":"FFFFFF","k":"009900","l":"009900","m":"009900","n":"FFFFFF","p":"10","q":"009900","r":100,"cnrs":"0.35","fwtickm":1}}</script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Adding `http:` to your source will allow it to run from a local file.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!! I added the second } bracket and it loaded in the browser! Thank you so much for the help. :)